# SQL Server connection string issue with multiple instances

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I used the same connection string for obtaining direct connection. But it is not getting connected when used from java code. What could be the problem?

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DEVSQL\mssql2008:1433
```

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host DEVSQL, named instance \mssql2008 has failed.

There are two instances of SQL Server (2005 and 2008) running on the same port 1433. So what would be the connection string.

- `\mssql2008` is not an instance.
- `DEVSQL` connects to the 2005 instance, while `DEVSQL\mssql2008` connects to the 2008 instance

Comment: are you connecting using jstd or microsoft's jar?

Comment: I am using microsoft's jar and I am using spring in my application

Comment: Change the port number of `Sql Server 2005`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslash

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DEVSQL\\mssql2008:1433
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing part of the connection string (`microsoft:` before `sqlserver:`. This should work:

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://DEVSQL\\mssql2008:1433
```

Answer (score 0):

Based in the information provided in your example, I cannot differentiate:

- Database server (maybe DEVSQL)
- SQL Server instance name (maybe mssql2008)
- Database name (for this, I'll just assume dbName)

With this info, you can construct your Connection String based in [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DEVSQL:1433;databaseName=dbName;instance=mssql2008.
```

Also, check that your MSSQL server has the TCP/IP connection enabled. Check here for more info:

- [How to: Enable the TCP/IP Protocol for a Database Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Protocols for MSSQL 2008](http://dbconvert.com/images/screenshot/mssql_manual/mssql_server_2008_express1.png) (image)